# Using llvm-header-guard with run-clang-tidy.py

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

I checked following links

- [What is proper LLVM header guard style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880907/what-is-proper-llvm-header-guard-style)
- [clang-tidy header guard style warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088319/clang-tidy-header-guard-style-warning)

but I can't solve the problem with the llvm-header-guard in combination with run-clang-tidy.py

I have following **CMakeLists.txt** file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Guard LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

file(WRITE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/guard/Foo/Bar.h
   "#ifndef GUARD_FOO_BAR_H\n"
   "#define GUARD_FOO_BAR_H\n"
   "class BarC {\n"
   "public:\n"
   "  BarC();\n"
   "  ~BarC();\n"
   "};\n"
   "#endif // GUARD_FOO_BAR_H\n"
)

file(WRITE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Foo/Bar.cpp
   "#include \"guard/Foo/Bar.h\"\n"
   "BarC::BarC(){}\n"
   "BarC::~BarC(){}\n"
)

include_directories(include)

add_library(Bar STATIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Foo/Bar.cpp)

add_custom_target(clang-tidy
   ALL
   COMMAND
      ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env "PATH=C:/LLVM/7.0.1-win64/bin;$ENV{PATH}" python C:/LLVM/7.0.1-win64/share/clang/run-clang-tidy.py -checks="llvm-header-guard" -header-filter=".*" -quiet
   DEPENDS
      Bar
   WORKING_DIRECTORY
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

and use following batch file (e.g. scirpt.bat)

```
set "PATH=C:\Ninja\1.8.2\bin;%PATH%"
set "PATH=C:\CMake\3.12.0-win64-x64\bin;%PATH%"
set "PATH=C:\MinGW\i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\bin;%PATH%"
set CXX=g++

del /F /Q build
del /F /Q lib
del /F /Q include
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -G "Ninja" ..
ninja
pause
```

this creates following output

```
1 warning generated.
C:\Users\Zlatan\Guard\build\../include\guard/Foo/Bar.h:1:9: warning: header guard does not follow preferred style [llvm-header-guard]
#ifndef GUARD_FOO_BAR_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        C:\USERS\ZLATAN\GUARD\BUILD\__\INCLUDE\GUARD\FOO\BAR_H
clang-tidy -header-filter=.* -checks=llvm-header-guard -p=C:\Users\Zlatan\Guard\build -quiet C:/Users/Zlatan/Guard/lib/Foo/Bar.cpp
```

Does somebody know how to run the clang-tidy python script correctly?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clang-tidy header guard style warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088319/clang-tidy-header-guard-style-warning)
This is a duplicate of your own question, there is nothing wrong with the way you're running it since it gives you a valid output.

Comment: When applying the suggested fix to the header file, the header guard looks like #define C:\USERS\ZLATAN\GUARD\BUILD\__\INCLUDE\GUARD\FOO\BAR_H. Therefore, I'm not able to compile the source any more. In my first question I only added the header file. In this questions I also added everything to reproduce and also added the information that I like to run clang-tidy with the run-clang-tidy.py script.