# How can I tell clang-tidy to check for pragma once instead of llvm-style header guards?

Tags: c++, llvm, header-files, pragma, clang-tidy

I would like to use clan-tidy. The program should check if I do have header guards, which is why I set the flag `llvm-header-guard`. Unfortunately this checks if the [header guards are llvm-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880907/what-is-proper-llvm-header-guard-style), which I don't want. I want to use `#pragma once`.

Does anyone have an idea how to tell clang-tidy to check for `#pragma once` instead of llvm-style header guards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such check in clang-tidy.

`#pragma once` is not part of the C++ standard (for good reasons) and until it becomes a part of the standard there is no reason to add it to clang-tidy.

You can write your own check but I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will write my own check, then and just disable the clang-tidy check.